# connected sets and function with different heights

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $F:\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous function (injective or embedding if need be).

Assume $C$ is a connected set (compact if necessary?) of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times [0,1]$ such that the last coordinate of every point in $F(\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times 0)$ is smaller than the last coordinate of every point of $C$. Assume that the last coordinate of every point of $C$ is smaller than the last coordinate of every point of $F(\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times 1)$. Why does it follows that $C\subseteq F(\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times [0,1])$? I think this is due to connectedness, but I am not sure how to formalize.

Comment: Why do you expect this to be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't follow: Let $n=2$, let $F:\mathbb{R}\times[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $F(x,y) = (y, \frac{2}{\pi}\arctan(x) + 6y - 3$) and let $C = [1,2]\times [0,1]$. Then
$$F(\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}) = \{0\}\times(-4,-2)$$
$$F(\mathbb{R}\times\{1\}) = \{1\}\times(2,4)$$
$$\sup\{y: (x,y)\in F(\mathbb{R}\times\{0\})\} = -2 \lt 0 = \inf\{y:(x,y)\in C\}$$
$$\sup\{y:(x,y)\in C\}=1 \lt 2 = \inf\{y: (x,y)\in F(\mathbb{R}\times\{1\})\} $$

Therefore $C$ satisfies all the conditions in the hypothesis (and it's compact), but clearly $C \not\subset F(\mathbb{R}\times[0,1]) $